# Pandas: best idiom for flexible aggregation levels

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to calculate some aggregated statistics on a `DataFrame` where I can aggregate using any set of categorical columns, **including the empty set** - that is, even just no aggregation at all. I emphasize the second because, at least among the portions of the API with which I am familiar, the choice to aggregate or not aggregate seems to lead to different sets of methods.

Here is my code:

```
n = 20
df = DataFrame ({
    "Region"    : np.random.choice (['North','South'], size=n) ,
    "Category"  : np.random.choice (['cat1','cat2'], size=n) ,
    "id"        : [i for i in range (1,n+1)] ,
    "val_1"     : np.random.randn(n) ,
    "val_2"     : [i for i in range (1,n+1)]
})

def agg_routine  (dataframe, var_names_cat):
    if (var_names_cat is not None):
        # Will fail if var_names_cat is None
        grouped = dataframe.groupby(var_names_cat)
        return grouped.agg ({
            "val_1" : np.sum ,
            "val_2" : np.average
        })
    else:
        return DataFrame ({
            "val_1" : Series (np.sum (dataframe["val_1"])) ,
            "val_2" : Series (np.average (dataframe["val_2"]))
        })

print (agg_routine(df, ["Region"]))
print (agg_routine(df, ["Region","Category"]))
print (agg_routine(df, None))
```

All of this works fine, but you can see what is happening in `agg_routine()` - there are two very different code paths depending on whether I am aggregating or not.

**My question is**: what is the best, most idiomatically correct way to do what I am doing without having to have the `if` branch and the two code paths - some set of methods that can work with both grouped and ungrouped data?

I am just trying to avoid duplicating the calculations across the two paths, as this could easily lead to errors.

### Update:

I came close with the following:

```
def agg_routine  (dataframe, var_names_cat):
    if (var_names_cat is not None):
        data_temp = dataframe.groupby(var_names_cat)
    else:
        data_temp = dataframe

    return DataFrame ({
        "val_1" : Series (data_temp.sum()["val_1"]) ,
        "val_2" : Series (data_temp.mean()["val_2"]) ,
    })
```

However, the problem here is that the `sum()` and `mean()` are applied to all columns, which can be a performance hit with medium-to-large data sets.

Comment: why not `data_temp["val_1"].sum()` ? and `data_temp["val_1"].mean()`

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that.  That is an excellent approach.  You ought to post this as an answer.

Comment: I tested the two cases of this, one summing all columns of your dataframe, and one summing only the sub selected column and even with this size of a dataframe I found that over 10,000 repetitions of each function, the current form, summing only the sub-selected columns, executes in just 32% of the execution time of the full summation.  Good intuition, that's a 3X boost in performance from that tweak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the same result, without the multi-column operation overhead if you modify your agg_routine as follows:

```
def agg_routine  (dataframe, var_names_cat):
    if (var_names_cat is not None):
        data_temp = dataframe.groupby(var_names_cat)
    else:
        data_temp = dataframe

    return DataFrame ({
        "val_1" : Series (data_temp["val_1"].sum()) ,
        "val_2" : Series (data_temp["val_2"].mean()) ,
    })
```

In this way, the Series is selected first, then either summed or averaged, depending upon the required operation. Thanks for recommending I post this as an answer.